# Iterate through command line parameters and append to string

Tags: bash

I have `./basscript parm1 parm2 parm3`

I want to iterate through the parms starting from `parm2` till `parmN` and append them to a variable.

How do I get `${COMPLETE}="parm1,parm2,parmN"`?

Comment: You should make sure that your sentences contain all the important words and that these words have all their letters in the right order, before posting a question. Also you should format it in a readable way.

Comment: basicly i ahev a script lets call it myscript.sh
the first cmd line parm is not important, the paramters after the first cmd lien parameter will be use to mail the result of the script to

I need to have "jo@gmail.com,sara@gmail.com" in one variable

after running ./myscript.sh whatevea jo@gmail.com sara@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

```
IFS=","
echo  "${*:2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
COMPLETE=""
shift
for a in "$@"
do
        if [ "$COMPLETE" == "" ]; then COMPLETE="$a"; else COMPLETE="$COMPLETE,$a" ; fi
done
echo $COMPLETE
```

This makes COMPLETE a comma-separated list of all the parameters, excluding the first.

Comment: If i put this in i get 
"[: 56: ==: unexpected operator "
?

Comment: shift
while test $# -gt 0
do


if [ "$MAIL_TO" == "" ]; then MAIL_TO="$1"; else MAIL_TO="$MAIL_TO,$1" ; fi

  shift
done

echo "Will mail to ${MAIL_TO}"